# Is it possible to stop users from changing their passwords with PAM?

Tags: password, pam, passwd

How can I stop users form changing their passwords with PAM? Is this possible? PAM can enforce password strength and the like, but it can reject all changes?

Comment: This is not via pam.d but I'm not sure it's even possible: https://superuser.com/a/547163

Comment: Why would you stop users from changing their passwords? That makes absolutely no sense. Do you also prevent them from logging in with private keys? You can of course remove the setuid bit of `passwd`, but it's stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I was able to stop it, by putting

```
password   required pam_deny.so
```

In the `/etc/pam.d/passwd`.